# Minute Utilization with Defined Timeframe - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am needing to count the number of active minutes, given a StartDTS and EndDTS for each row, that fall within a defined timeframe.

For example:

RowDTS:

1. [StartDTS= 06:36:00] [EndDTS= 08:42:00]
2. [StartDTS= 09:37:00] [EndDTS= 13:42:00]
3. [StartDTS= 14:21:00] [EndDTS= 18:21:00]

Timeframe:

- [Time_Frame_Start= 07:00:00] [Time_Frame_End= 15:30:00]

If any part of the time between the StartDTS and EndDTS fall within the Time_Frame_Start and Time_Frame_End, those minutes inside the defined time frame should be counted.

```
CREATE TABLE #RowDTS (Indentifier varchar(255), StartDTS datetime2(7), EndDTS datetime2(7))
INSERT INTO #RowDTS
VALUES
('4318','2018-04-03 09:18:00.0000000','2018-04-03 10:20:00.0000000'),
('4397','2018-04-20 11:34:00.0000000','2018-04-20 12:27:00.0000000'),
('4459','2018-04-20 11:06:00.0000000','2018-04-20 11:54:00.0000000'),
('4739','2018-04-12 13:46:00.0000000','2018-04-12 17:34:00.0000000'),
('4845','2018-04-18 10:26:00.0000000','2018-04-18 15:18:00.0000000'),
('4933','2018-04-19 07:24:00.0000000','2018-04-19 09:51:00.0000000'),
('5063','2018-04-03 07:57:00.0000000','2018-04-03 11:00:00.0000000'),
('4855','2018-04-03 11:01:00.0000000','2018-04-03 11:51:00.0000000'),
('4858','2018-04-05 07:26:00.0000000','2018-04-05 11:12:00.0000000'),
('4972','2018-04-11 14:02:00.0000000','2018-04-11 16:36:00.0000000')
SELECT * FROM #RowDTS
```

This is essentially the output I am looking for:

```
+---------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+
| RowIdentifier |          StartDTS           |           EndDTS            | UtilizedMinutes |
+---------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+
|        431859 | 2018-04-03 09:18:00.0000000 | 2018-04-03 10:20:00.0000000 |                 |
|        439784 | 2018-04-20 11:34:00.0000000 | 2018-04-20 12:27:00.0000000 |                 |
|        445989 | 2018-04-20 11:06:00.0000000 | 2018-04-20 11:54:00.0000000 |                 |
|        473939 | 2018-04-12 13:46:00.0000000 | 2018-04-12 17:34:00.0000000 |                 |
|        484568 | 2018-04-18 10:26:00.0000000 | 2018-04-18 15:18:00.0000000 |                 |
|        493333 | 2018-04-19 07:24:00.0000000 | 2018-04-19 09:51:00.0000000 |                 |
|        506386 | 2018-04-03 07:57:00.0000000 | 2018-04-03 11:00:00.0000000 |                 |
|        485551 | 2018-04-03 11:01:00.0000000 | 2018-04-03 11:51:00.0000000 |                 |
|        485882 | 2018-04-05 07:26:00.0000000 | 2018-04-05 11:12:00.0000000 |                 |
|        497230 | 2018-04-11 14:02:00.0000000 | 2018-04-11 16:36:00.0000000 |                 |
+---------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Is that the literal values in that column?

Comment: No those are arbitrary times. wanted to make sure and illustrate that some times could overlap before or after the timeframe and some could be completely contained within the time frame.

Comment: Can you provide [legitimate sample data and expected output](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/), with the DDL? That column looks like a varchar

Comment: What is the data type of underlying columns?

Comment: My apologies, I will work on getting the sample data updated, first time poster!

Comment: No worries at all--i understand completely.

Comment: The startDTS and EndDTS colums are (datetime2(7), null)

Comment: I'm going to edit your question to help you out on how to add some sample data. be sure to edit it afterwards and provide real data.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I have some usable data posted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed your time range data type is TIME and all of the StartDTS and EndDTS values are within the same day. This query would do the job, but if the date values can fall into different days, you need CTE to get the same result.

```
DECLARE @TimeFrameStart TIME = '10:00:00';
DECLARE @TimeFrameEnd TIME = '15:30:00';

SELECT [Indentifier], 
    CONVERT(TIME, [StartDTS]) AS [StartDTS],
    CONVERT(TIME, [EndDTS]) AS [EndDTS],

    CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(TIME, [StartDTS]) >= @TimeFrameStart AND CONVERT(TIME, [EndDTS]) <= @TimeFrameEnd
        THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [StartDTS], [EndDTS])
    WHEN CONVERT(TIME, [StartDTS]) <= @TimeFrameStart AND CONVERT(TIME, [EndDTS]) >= @TimeFrameEnd
        THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @TimeFrameStart, @TimeFrameEnd)
    WHEN CONVERT(TIME, [StartDTS]) <= @TimeFrameStart AND CONVERT(TIME, [EndDTS]) > @TimeFrameStart
        THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @TimeFrameStart, CONVERT(TIME, [EndDTS]))
    WHEN CONVERT(TIME, [EndDTS]) >= @TimeFrameEnd AND CONVERT(TIME, [StartDTS]) < @TimeFrameEnd
        THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(TIME, [StartDTS]), @TimeFrameEnd)
    ELSE 0
    END AS [UtilizedMinutes]
FROM #RowDTS;
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: An alternative is to use `DateDiff()` with two `case` expressions as arguments: one to determine the start time and another for the end time. Modern versions of SQL Server could use [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) rather than `case` for a more compact solution.

Comment: Would you be willing to expand on creating a CTE to account for time frames that may cross over midnight?